# Angular testing - Error generating coverage report

Tags: angular, typescript, code-coverage, source-maps, istanbul

I'm trying to get a coverage report from `ng test --code-coverage`. Without coverage, the tests are running without problems, but with it I get this error:

```
ERROR [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
  at fixPathSeparators (<path>\node_modules\karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter\src\util.js:20:21)
  at Object.fixWebpackSourcePaths (<path>\node_modules\karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter\src\util.js:41:16)
  at Object.keys.forEach.filename (<path>\node_modules\karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter\src\reporter.js:46:44)
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at addCoverage (<path>\node_modules\karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter\src\reporter.js:43:27)
  at createReport (<path>\node_modules\karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter\src\reporter.js:98:7)
  at browsers.forEach.browser (<path>\node_modules\karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter\src\reporter.js:213:9)
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at Collection.forEach (<path>\node_modules\karma\lib\browser_collection.js:93:21)
  at CoverageIstanbulReporter.onRunComplete (<path>\node_modules\karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter\src\reporter.js:212:16)
  at Server.<anonymous> (<path>\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
  at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)
  at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
  at Timeout._onTimeout (<path>\node_modules\karma\lib\executor.js:51:17)
  at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
  at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
```

Some debugging showed that the `sourceMap` used inside Istanbul has not attribute `sourceRoot`. I tried to add this to several config files with no luck.

In my `karam.conf.js` I have:

```
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
  dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
  reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
}
```

Very strange is the fact that my project contains a library with separate tests. They work with an identical configuration.

**Facts**:

- Angular 6.1.0
- Jasmine 2.99.1
- Karma 1.7.1
- Karma Coverage Istanbul Reporter: 2.0.0

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing reports in your `coverageIstanbulReporter` to: `reports: ['text-summary', 'html', 'lcovonly'],` . I'm getting a similar error as you, if I leave out text-summary, so might be worth a try.

Comment: @MichaelKie Thank you, unfortunately the error is still there with this change :-(

Comment: Maybe try updating Karma Coverage Istanbul Reporter, I'm using `~2.0.0`, `0.2.2` seems very old.

Comment: Oh sorry, I posted the wrong number. It is `~2.0.0` for me, too. I update the original post.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/MichaelKiener95/f3adc6249d7a2ba4a66d52b3e4d48af5) is the exact config i'm using and I don't have any problems with code coverage, if that doesn't help you I'm out of ideas, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I have a custom library which ist part of the project and is used in a component with `<clib-element></clib-element>`.

In the `component.spec.ts` of the parent component I imported it like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  imports: [ CLibModule ] /* Don't do it like this */
})
```

Instead, I had to mock the used component. I wrote this mock component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'clib-element' /* Important: Same selector as real component */
})
export class ElementMockComponent {
  /* declare used methods and attributes */
}
```

Declare it in the test file:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  declarations: [ ElementMockComponent ]
})
```

... and the error is gone. Hope this helps others, too!